# Optimization of algebraic computation

Tags: performance, wolfram-mathematica

Using mathematica, I can compute the mathematical representation of a function that I then want to code in C++.

Say I get something like:

```
f=Log[2*x+3*y]+Sin[4*x+6*y]
```

It obviously makes sense in that case to do the computation:

```
temp=2*x+3*y
f=Log[temp]+Sin[2*temp]
```

Is there a way to get the expression that would reduce the execution time / number of operations / size of the expression or any good metric given a more complex mathematical expression?

Comment: For optimizations like the one you posted, at least, I know that optimizing compilers should do it for you. Much more complicated is probably provably impossible.

Comment: @rogaos I know any good optimizer will remove common subexpressions that appear liteally, but do most of them really do the algebraic analysis to detect the common factor in the above code?

Comment: @Barmar ah, I misread the question a little. No, I don't know if any that will. If you originally wrote it as 2 * (2*x + 3*y) it will optimize, otherwise it won't. You could write a method to factor beforehand... but that would probably be a slower program anyway

Comment: In practice, I don't think this kind of simplification is going to be very important. If the expression is more complicated, the performance will be dominated by expensive operations like `Log` and `Sin`, and a few extra additions or multiplications in the arguments won't make too much difference. If you have something like this in an inner loop and performance is poor, you could concentrate on trying to factor it yourself then.

Comment: there are of course instances where there are repeated sub expressions that are far more complicated. Take this question to mathematica.stackexchange.com, however id suggest you do some searching as i suspect this has been discussed there previously.

Comment: It has been discussed there [previously](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2885/52). But, it doesn't simplify your code. Ideally, it should work with yours, too, but any system has to recognize that `4 x+6 y = 2 (2 x + 3 y)`. Unfortunately, `2 (2 x + 3 y)` is more complex than `4 x + 6 y`, so it would require an optimizer that could back track.

Answer (score 0):

Although it doesn't work for your simple example, what you can try is the following in *Mathematica*

```
Experimental`OptimizeExpression[{Log[(2*x^3 + 3*y)^2] + Sin[2 (2*x^3 + 6*y)^2]}]
```

As result you get

```
Experimental`OptimizedExpression[
 Block[{Compile`$3, Compile`$4}, Compile`$3 = x^3; 
  Compile`$4 = 2 Compile`$3; 
  {Log[(Compile`$4 + 3 y)^2] + Sin[2 (Compile`$4 + 6 y)^2]}]]
```